# Postgres function getting unique constraint violation

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a `plpgsql` function containing this

```
update allplaces set visittime = now() where visittime is null and person = 'me' and place = 'this';
if (FOUND) then
    update allplaces set visittime = null where person = 'me' and place != 'this';
    return true;
else
    return false;
end if;
```

The `allplaces` table has a unique constraint as `create unique index indexallplaces on allplaces (person) where visittime is not null` which means that a given `person` can only have 1 record with `visittime` that is not null.

I'm trying to switch the `visittime` from whichever record of mine (`person` equals `'me'`) it was before (`place` equals whatever) to the one where `place` equals `'this'`, but I get a unique constraint violation for the unique index I mentioned. I can't set the old value to null without changing ensuring a new value has been set, hence the need for the `if (FOUND)` check.

How can I change this postgres function to work? The function is using `plpgsql` but it could be normal SQL too if that works better in this case.

EDIT

```
perform from allplaces where visittime is null and person = 'me' and place = 'this' and ...otherconditions...;
if (FOUND) then
    update allplaces set visittime = null where person = 'me';
    update allplaces set visittime = now() where person = 'me' and place = 'this' and ...otherconditions...;
    return true;
else
    return false;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just changing the query to use a case like so

```
update allplaces 
set visittime = case when place <> 'this' then null else now() end  
where person = 'me';
```

This will update all visittimes with null, except the ones where place= this.
This should work given that there is only 1 row of (me,this) at the time of the update

Comment: Unfortunately, the query may raise a duplicate key error.

Comment: If there are 2+ rows with (me,this) at the time of the update, any query will raise the exception. You mean that even with just 1 row it could still raise it?
edit: or i have not evaluated the 'not null' part of the constrain properly..

Comment: The problem is that the table is constrained with a partial unique index and may contain multiple rows for a `person` with null `visittime`.